# Jaxb not unmarshaling unicode 1F609

Tags: java, xml, unicode, jaxb

We got a ParseError when unmarshalling unicode Character 0x1f609 (xml version 1.0).

It seems to be a valid xml char according to this documentation:
https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets

Simply removing this character would be no solution, because there could be other similar characters in future XML documents.

How could we solve this? 
Is it a JAXB-Bug?

Or do we have to remove all characters within another character-range? (e.g. all emoticons: http://www.isthisthingon.org/unicode/index.phtml?page=1F&subpage=6&hilite=1F609#Emoticons)

Answer (score 0):

- First double check what is running JVM default Charset is and what is your XML Charset.

  JVM - `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`

  XML - `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
- Probably to make it work, strings where such characters can appear,
  either need to be URL encoded or `<![CDATA[` must be used explicitly.

UPD: 
Also you need to check how that character looks in your XML input exactly. If it is HTML encoded as `&#x1F609;` or `&#128521;` problem is exactly about `&` character not about "winking face". `&` cannot be parsed from XML. It must be either XML encoded as `&amp;` or in CDATA. As long as CDATA is not an option you may need to have an Interceptor upfront to make a String XML encoded.

Comment: JVM default charset is set to windows-1252.
When i change it to:

`System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");`

unmarshalling fails again. XML encoding is set to UTF-8, too
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

The second solution (URL-encoding or `<![CDATA[`) must be done by the provider of the xml-data, right?

this may be a problem because we get it from a third part Webservice.

Nevertheless 0x1f609 seems to be a valid xml character to me. Or am i wrong?

Comment: Please look at updated answer. I think that is a problem. Not JAXB it-self.

Comment: The Exception-Message is as follows:
`Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[4,274]
Message: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1f609) was found in the element content of the document.`

So i think it is correctly XML-enccoded?

Comment: how actual string value looks like in XML? something as `<textMessage>this is a smile face ???what is there for  0x1f609???</textMessage>` ?

Comment: This is how we get it from the web service:  
`<text> some text  some text .....</text>`

This is the log output:  
`<text> some text <U+1F609> some text .....</text>`

But i think the log output is not UTF-8 encoded

Comment: If log is not UTF-8 encoded who did translation from bytes to string as `<U+1F609>`?  To me it looks like it is exactly what you have as input and `<U+1F609>` definitely cannot be parsed. it must be like &lt;U+1F609&gt;. So, I guess you have only one option - create an interceptor before Unmarshalling and make string XML escaped.

Comment: we now solved it by simply stripping off all emoticons